# Redirect traffic to an IP into a LXC container

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, virtualbox, lxd

I have a dedicated server (running Ubuntu 20.04) running a VM in Virtualbox. This VM (also running on Ubuntu 20.04) has several applications running in dedicated LXC containers managed by LXD. The VM is connected to the host using a **Host-only Adapter** on the interface *vboxnet0* and the containers use an LXD bridge. So I have the following structure (the IP are obviously not the real ones):

- Dedicated server: public IP 66.66.66.66, host-only adapter IP 55.55.55.1
- VM: Host-only adapter IP 55.55.55.2, LXD bridge IP 44.44.44.1
- Application container: LXD bridge IP 44.44.44.2

What i'm trying to do is to redirect the traffic to the public IP and a specific port (let's say 80) to the container hosting the adapted service, something like 66.66.66.66:80 -> 44.44.44.2:80.

The idea I had was to create a specific route in my dedicated server in order to make the LXD subnet accessible:

- ip route add 44.44.44.0/24 via 55.55.55.2 dev vboxnet0

Then to setup an IPTABLES redirection (using information from this post:[Channel all the traffic on an IP to a VM](https://serverfault.com/questions/747559/channel-all-the-traffic-on-an-ip-to-a-vm))

- iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 66.66.66.66 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 44.44.44.2
- iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 44.44.44.2 -j MASQUERADE

After that, i'm still unable to reach my container using the public ip.
What am i doing wrong ? Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is lxc's proxy devices.  they're much easier to use than trying to mangle iptables yourself.  see https://blog.simos.info/how-to-use-the-lxd-proxy-device-to-map-ports-between-the-host-and-the-containers/

something like
lxc config device add yourcontainer myport80 proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:80 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:80

or if you want to be more specific about the ip you listen on, then perhaps
lxc config device add yourcontainer myport80 proxy listen=tcp:66.66.66.66:80 connect=tcp:127.0.0.1:80

what this does is listen on the host network (every ip, or something specific) - in this case tcp port 80 - and proxies that through to the container called "yourcontainer" on the container's localhost address at tcp port 80.  "myoport80" in this example is the name of the proxy device - you can call it whatever you like.

Simos' blog post above gives a better intro, and there's more detail here: https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/instances/#type-proxy