# How Can I Use the Iptables but Not Converting the Resource IP?

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, port-forwarding, ip-address

I want to deflect some IP address that we access using any tools (like nmap, medusa, etc) to the another IP Address.

For more details:
I have 2 IP Addresses, First IP Address is `192.168.1.7` and the Second is `192.168.1.6`. When I want to access the first IP Address using another PC in the same LAN, I want to deflect that to the Second IP Address on port 22, so I using Iptables for that as you can see here, I add some rule on the second IP Address pc:

`echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.43.7`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

after I tried that, it was work. But, I really need the IP Address information about who was accessing the IP Address because the result show that it's only the **first** IP Address that was accessing the second IP Address, not the **third** one. Can you help me please? Because it always converting the IP Address Source and I don't know why.

Oh, I also tried using any tools port forwarder like **rinetd**, **socat**, etc. But it doesn't work. Do you have any idea for this? I really need help.

[Update] :

I've tried using SNAT on the rule in iptables but it has same result. I read this post [How to do the port forwarding from one ip to another ip in same network?](https://serverfault.com/questions/586486/how-to-do-the-port-forwarding-from-one-ip-to-another-ip-in-same-network) but I don't know what must I do with that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iptables DNAT single port](https://serverfault.com/questions/748109/iptables-dnat-single-port)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry but no :(

Comment: Did you actually try it? What happened?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it said filtered state for the port and what I want is open

Comment: You still have to allow the traffic in the firewall on the destination host!

Comment: Can you give a more complete description of your objective in your question? Your question does not show where from do you want to connect to `192.168.1.7` port 22. What is the role of `192.168.1.7` device in the network? Is it a router for public internet?

Answer (score 0):

```
Server-A = 192.168.1.7
Server-B = 192.168.1.6
Client-PC = 10.20.20.3
```

From what you are trying to achieve, the MASQUERADE rule is the culprit and must be removed. Here is a scenario. When `Client-PC` attempts to connect to `Server-A`, it must be redirected to `Server-B` on `TCP 22`. From `Server-B` perspective, traffic is coming from `10.20.20.3`

On the host that is acting as a Linux gateway, do the following:

```
$ sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 192.168.1.7 --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.6:22
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

From `Server-B`, make sure it knows how how to send return traffic back to `10.20.20.3`

If not, then add a static route on `Server-B`

```
$ sudo ip route add 10.20.20.3 via X.X.X.X # Where X.X.X.X is the IP of the Linux gateway
```