# Why are iptables rules to redirect incoming traffic blocking other ports/service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I have followed some posts in order to redirect all incoming traffic public IP to an internal IP address using iptables. I set `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and used the following rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9080 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.178.1:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

The idea is that I have a remote server (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) which I can always reach using a reverse SSH tunnel. In that network I would like to access some devices like gateway and other devices. With the iptables I would like to be able to access, for example, the GUI of the gateway. On the local network the rules work!

The problem is that on the server I cannot set up the tunnel to redirect 9080 to 192.168.178.1:80. When I try other things on the server, for example ping I get the following:

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

And when I set the tunnel:

```
$ ssh user@remoteserverfortunnel.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname remoteserverfortunnel.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

When I set up the tunnel before the rules (removing then with -D), and adding the rules again a get this when requesting the `remoteserverfortunnel.com:9080`

```
ssh -N -R 9080:localhost:9080 user@remoteserverfortunnel.com
user@remoteserverfortunnel.com's password: 
connect_to localhost port 9080: failed.
```

I can still login the server using the normal port 22 SSH.

My question is, why are the rules blocking the tunnel? Is there an extra rule I have to add?

EDIT:

I added the interface option:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp2s0 -p tcp --dport 9080 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.103:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

The failure in name resolution is solved. Unfortunately the idea using the tunnel still does not work, I get `connect_to localhost port 9080: failed.`

I did found out that I could also tunnel direct to the device, for example using `ssh -N -R 9080:192.168.178.1:80 user@remoteserverfortunnel.com`. Using this avoids using the iptables, I would still want to the IP tables option to learn. Some devices also do not work as expect through the tunnel.

Comment: Please see the linked [post](https://serverfault.com/q/748109/126632) at the top of this page. If it does not help you, then edit your post to show the results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it solved part of the problem. But not sure were the problem is now