# Which iptables rules allow me to fake a remote DNS answer with a local DNS running on the router?

Tags: iptables, internal-dns, dnsmasq

- A machine has a DNS set to 8.8.8.8
- The network router has an ad hoc DNS running (say `dnsmasq`)

**Which `iptables` rules allows to fake the response from the remote server 8.8.8.8 with the local router DNS?**

For instance, if the router DNS is associating `google.fr` to the IP of `google.co.uk`, I want to be able to see this from the router (`192.168.1.2` is the ansewer)

```
# dnsspoof
192.168.1.2.38072 > 8.8.8.8.53:  31752+ A? google.fr
8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.1.2.38072: 31752+ A google.co.uk
```

Comment: Assuming  that your router is running Linux http://serverfault.com/q/586486/37681

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
[...]
```